# How to make a count upward timer with label

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two `buttons` and one `label`. The first `button` is "start", the second one is "stop", and the `label` has a text of "00 : 00 : 00".

What I want is when I click on the `start` button i want the `label` to start counting upwards until I click on the `stop` button.

I have tried a lot of ways but most of them did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Please show us a [mcve] of your best attempt.

Comment: " I have tried a lot of ways but most of them did not work..." So you found at least one way that *does* work? Why didn't you go with one of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a combination of a `Stopwatch` (to keep track of the elapsed time) and a `Timer` (to update the label text at regular intervals).

First, we can just call `stopwatch.Start` in the `Start` button's `Click` event, and `stopwatch.Stop` in the `Stop` button's `Click` event. We may want to add a `Reset` button as well, using a similar pattern to control the stopwatch through the UI.

Next we can set our `Timer` to run every `100` milliseconds, which should give a fairly snappy display update (but adjust as you see fit). Then we can add a `Tick` event for it which simply calls an `UpdateDisplay()` method that will update the label with the current elapsed time of the stopwatch. Finally we will also call `Timer.Start()` and `Timer.Stop()` in the `Click` event of the appropriate buttons, so the timer isn't running needlessly while the stopwatch is stopped.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Timer _labelUpdateTimer = new Timer();
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Custom format string for displaying the elapsed time as "00 : 00 : 00"
    private const string TimeFormat = "hh\\ \\:\\ mm\\ \\:\\ ss";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _labelUpdateTimer.Interval = 100;
        _labelUpdateTimer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        UpdateDisplay();
    }

    private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        lblDisplay.Text = _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(TimeFormat);
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateDisplay();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _stopwatch.Start();
        UpdateDisplay();
        _labelUpdateTimer.Start();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        UpdateDisplay();
        _labelUpdateTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```